# Reformat this math formula to not need parenthesis

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a pricing equation that I am working with for an eCommerce site and I need to reformat this equation to not need parenthesis.

Original Formula:

> {price} + ({length} * ({ppf} + {jacket_price})) + {c1_price} + {c2_price} + {pe_price}

Current Formula:

> {length} * ({ppf} + {jacket_price}) + {price} + {c1_price} + {c2_price} + {pe_price}

Can this equation be restructured further to not need parenthesis?  The important part is making sure that `{ppf}` and `{jacket_price}` are added and then multiplied by `{length}` before being added to all the other values.

Sample Data:

- Price = 10.00
- Length = 10
- PPF = 0.75
- Jacket Price = 2
- C1 Price = 1
- C2 Price = 3
- PE Price = 4.95

Comment: Why do you want to do this without needing parentheses? I don't think there's a reasonable way to do this other than something like $\text{{length} * {ppf} + {length} * {jacket_price} + {price} + {c1_price} + {c2_price} + {pe_price}}$.

Comment: I agree, I would love to add parenthesis to make a more logical equation, however, the website coding is not as stable with parenthesis sets as part of the equation.

Comment: @mvw No, the curly brackets need to surround each "variable".

Comment: @qaphla you may want to add your comment as an answer

Comment: That parentheses introduce instability is weird. It makes one wonder if the substituted {var} expressions are landing within a proper scope that is able to evaluate the resulted expressions. That is why I suggested to look if the template engine supports {expression} substitutions,  because the parser evaluating the expression might be better working.

Comment: @mvw  True, I will email the developers regarding this, however, it may be how the formula is parsed.  All documentation and examples indicate that curly brackets are needed around each "variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By distributing {length} you get

{length} * {ppf} + {length} * {jacket_price} + {price} + {c1_price} + {c2_price} + {pe_price}